# MongoDB indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm in the process of converting my Rails app to use mongodb through mongoid. I have two questions relating to indexes. I think I know the answer, but I want confirmation from someone who has more experience with mongodb.

Let's look at the following example where I have one relational association between `Users` and `Posts`.

user.rb

```
class User  
    has_many_related :posts  
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post  
    belongs_to_related :user  
end
```

Now when I look at the indexes created through the MongoHQ interface, I notice the following two:

1. Key Name: `_id_`
   Indexed Field: `_id`
   Unique: `<blank>`
   **Is the id guaranteed to be unique? If so, why isn't unique set. If not, how can I set this and do I need to?**
2. Key Name: `user_id_1`
   Indexed Field: `user_id`
   Unique: `false`
   **Am I correct in assuming the Indexed Field is the field name in the collection? Just want to confirm as Key Name has the `_1` after it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `_id` in MongoDB is always unique. It's the primary key, which is why setting `UNIQUE` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is very clearly described indexes in MongoDB [Indexing Overview](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-primary).

_id

The _id index is a unique index** on the _id field, and MongoDB creates this index by default on all collections. You cannot delete the index on _id.

The _id field is the primary key for the collection, and every document must have a unique _id field. You may store any unique value in the _id field. The default value of _id is ObjectID on every insert()

**  Although the index on _id is unique, the getIndexes() method will not print unique: true in the mongo shell.

Comment: Try to leave complete answer here, links are temporary and are good only for further documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the _id value manually in MongoDB, then the type will be set to a special BSON datatype that consists of a 12-byte binary value.

The 12-byte value consists of a 4-byte timestamp, a 3-byte machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a 3-byte counter. Due to this design, this value has a resonably high probability of being unique.

Reference: The Definitive Guide to MongoDB: The NoSQL Database for Cloud and Desktop Computing (book)